# Excel: Plot order total in map coordinates

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have a set of data that looks like this:

```
-X--Y----Amount-
AE  24  $178,00 
Y   27  $162,00 
AD  34  $680,00 
AK  35  $178,00 
Y   25  $29,00 
U   23  $178,00 
X   38  $193,00 
AC  30  $226,00 
AK  39  $152,00 
AJ  34  $217,00 
AC  35  $183,00 
AA  22  $211,00 
Z   19  $172,00 
AJ  32  $187,00 
AF  26  $272,00 
AI  27  $220,00 
AJ  34  $320,00 
AB  32  $183,00 
AB  35  $272,00 
AC  32  $207,00 
AB  28  $178,00 
AC  30  $168,00 
AC  28  $178,00 
AB  32  $310,00 
AD  30  $188,00 
AB  35  $188,00
```

The sample above is only an excerpt of the total dataset of 16K rows

Each row represents a single delivery order, where the 2 first columns are the map coordinate and the third the purchase amount.

Would it be possible to plot the above data in a chart or coordinate system. Where the each plot should be a summary of all sales in the same map coordinate.

Also a similar chart of order count would be nice to have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may not answer it 100%, but this seems like a great use for a PivotTable. Just a basic PivotTable where you put your X values in the columns, Y values in the Rows, and then you can add both the Sum of Amount and Count of Amount as your values.

[image]

Sorting by both Row and Column will give you a coordinate system in the pivot table without having to resort to a chart. You could make it feel more chart-y by using conditional formatting on the cells containing the values where you could paint them different colors based on size or some other criteria.

[image]

Besides that though.. I don't believe excel is going to be the friendliest environment plotting an arbitrary coordinate system.

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm! First time I used Pivot table. But the builder and a brief tutorial video on Youtube, had me finished in under an hour. I had to do some extensive RegEx on the source data in order to make it fully filterable. Boss = Impressed B-)